# FreeBSD flag to ignore permission errors when searching file for a string

Tags: grep, freebsd

Im using the following to serch for a string in all the files in a directory.

```
grep -Flr --include "*" 'mystring' /modules/
```

Which works perectly fine and returns the files which contain the string. However I also get a list of files with permission denied next to them which means looking for the results a bit harder.

Is there a flag to pass to the command to ignore outputting permission denied errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I usually just use:

```
grep -Flr --include "*" 'mystring' /modules/ 2>/dev/null
```

which will throw away all output to standard error, assuming you have a shell allowing for `2>` standard error redirection. If not, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720246/redirect-stderr-to-stdout-in-c-shell).

If (as you seem to indicate in your comment), your version of grep outputs its errors to standard output rather than standard error, you can filter that output with something like:

```
grep -Flr --include "*" 'mystring' /modules/ | egrep -v 'Permission denied|ERROR'
```

This will throw away lines based on whatever pattern you deem is necessary.

Comment: Thanks however for me it didn't work.

I found the following to work:
grep -Flr --include "*" 'mystring' /modules/ | grep -v Perm

Comment: The default shell on FreeBSD is `tcsh`, which doesn't recognize `2>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BSD grep, use the `-s` flag;

```
grep -Flrs --include "*" 'mystring' /modules/
```

Additionally, I think you can drop the `--include "*"` because BSD grep reads directories by default and recurses over them if you use `-r` or `-R`.